Crow syntax for optional query parameters
I'm quite new to C++ and can't get my head around the documentation for Crow Web server.
What I want is to mock an RPC-endpoint, allowing query-parameters to be empty, and if so default them to "". The idea of using .get(value, defaultStr) seems missing or gone..
I'm getting an exception even asking for a parameter that's not there, and no option to set a default value from what i see in the docs.
(tagging with flask since Crow seems to be based upon it)
Here's what i've got:
    CROW_ROUTE(api, "/rpc")
    .methods(crow::HTTPMethod::Get)([&rpcParser](const crow::request &req) {
        // Extract query parameters
        std::string method = req.url_params.get("method");
        std::string key = req.url_params.get("key");
        std::string value = req.url_params.get("value");

        // Check if any of the parameters are missing
        if (method.empty()) {
            return crow::response(400, "Missing required query parameters");
        }
        if (key.empty())
            key = "";
        if (value.empty())
            value = "";

        // Split the method at the first dot
        size_t dot_pos = method.find('.');
        if (dot_pos != std::string::npos) {
            std::string class_name = method.substr(0, dot_pos);   // Extract the part before the dot
            std::string method_name = method.substr(dot_pos + 1); // Extract the part after the dot

            // Call the RPC parser with the split values
            rpcParser.parse(class_name, method_name, key, value);
        } else {
            // Handle the error when there is no dot in the method
            // For example, you might want to send an error response
            return crow::response(400, "Invalid method format");
        }

        // Return a response
        return crow::response(200, "Request processed successfully");
    });


Update: here's the doc for the qs (version diff but the only one there is..): https://crowcpp.org/master/reference/classcrow_1_1query__string.html

If you are getting an exception you should provide the full detail of that exception in the question. It might not mean much to you but to someone knowledgeable it might be the clue to answering this question.

Note to self and others:
.get() returns a char* , not std:string
easy way out (may be prettier ways):
    std::string method = req.url_params.get("method") ? req.url_params.get("method") : "";
    std::string key = req.url_params.get("key") ? req.url_params.get("key") : "";
    std::string value = req.url_params.get("value") ? req.url_params.get("value") : "";

